# PHP Chinese Captcha

Tags: php, localization, captcha, cjk

Is there a captcha available for PHP which displays Chinese characters but isn't JavaScript dependent?

Comment: Captchas do not require JavaScript at all.

Comment: You *really* want to torture your users, don't you? ;-D Just kidding, if your audience can be expected to be able to write Chinese, that's actually a great idea.

Comment: I'm trying to do this because we have a lot of Chinese users and I'm implementing reCAPTCHA and even with custom translations, the captcha image stills displays letters from the Latin alphabet (as you'd expect) and the audio challenge is in English (but I'm not as worried about that)

Comment: Now why would I possibly get downvotes for this question?

Comment: just fyi all the chinese web sites I have used show numbers or latin alphabet - Chinese people are going to know these anyway so why torture yourself?

Comment: @JIStone thanks. I was looking for a numeric captcha as an alternative to recaptcha because I didn't think Chinese characters had Latin letters.

Comment: @Adam - Chinese students learn the pinyin romanization before learning characters, and pinyin is also the standard method for typing Chinese on a computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BotDetect captcha supports Chinese characters since the version 3.0
http://captcha.biz/localizations/chinese-captcha.html

A few days ago they released PHP version as well.
http://captcha.biz/php-captcha.html

It works with JavaScript disabled.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this
http://www.phpkode.com/scripts/item/hippo-chinese-cert-code/

hope it helps

Comment: Can't get it working, but I guess you've still answered the question; there is one out there. (Even though it's not working, it probably is/was in use.)