# PHP Japanese captcha

Tags: php, localization, captcha

Is there a PHP captcha out there which displays Japanese characters?
(Cannot be JavaScript dependent)

---

### EDIT:

To anyone saying this is a possible duplicate. Surely this isn't a duplicate because the [*"possible duplicate"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042022/php-chinese-captcha/6042120#6042120) and this are two different questions as **the correct answer to each (if any) would be different!**

The answer to the other question might be `"use this chinese captcha plugin: http://..."`. **That won't answer this question!**

Comment: What’s with your other Captcha questions?

Comment: Surely these are two different questions as the correct answer to each (if any) would be different? The answer to question A might be "use this chinese captcha plugin: http://...". That won't answer question B!

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I'm using reCaptcha for languages based on the Latin/Roman alphabet so if I were to create the captcha myself I guess I'd do that. But I'd preferably like to use a library, etc.

Comment: @Adam: In my personal experience, using Japanese Captcha is not always a good idea. As you may know not all people know all kanjis and if your idea is to obfuscate the visual output (as most Captchas work), it will be extremely difficult (even for Japanese). If for simple English words sometimes is already difficult, imagine using kanjis!. If still want to do it, my suggestion will be to use the GD library to display common Japanese words as images (and use a hash to compare). Applying OCR to those images is complicated enough (which makes it relatively safe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BotDetect captcha supports Japanese characters since the version 3.0
http://captcha.biz/localizations/japanese-captcha.html

A few days ago they released PHP version as well.
http://captcha.biz/php-captcha.html

It works with JavaScript disabled

Answer (score 0):

> To anyone saying this is a possible duplicate. Surely this isn't a duplicate because the "possible duplicate" and this are two different questions as the correct answer to each (if any) would be different!

Actually, it would answer your question. You just need to get a file with Japanese text. Or do you not know a lot of kanjis come from China?

Get yourself a file with a bunch of Japanese words and replace the current file with it, make the necessary modifications to adapt the new format if it doesn't work and you're good to go. Reinventing the wheel here is silly.

Comment: I am asking "Is there a PHP captcha out there...", not "How do I write a Japanese captcha". An expected answer would be a URL pointing to an API/plugin or downloadable.

Comment: `"The current file"` is reCaptcha by the way.